# "Notice: Undefined index: action in" а также "Notice: Undefined variable: install " в плагине vbridge для vbulletin и wordpress

Tags: wordpress, index, variable, vbulletin

Есть плагин для связи движков Vbulletin и Wordpress (это для поиска, вдруг кто будет искать такую ошибку).

Он почему-то ругается на эти ошибки:

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in /vbbridge.php on line 17
Notice: Undefined index: action in /vbbridge.php on line 23
Notice: Undefined variable: install in /vbbridge.php on line 33
```

﻿
Сам файл:

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: vBulletin Wordpress Bridge
Plugin URI: http://www.lampwrights.com/
Description: This plugin will bridge to VB so VB users can comment on articles bridge users.  For detailed instructions please visit <a href='http://www.lampwrights.com'>Lampwrights.com</a>.
Version: 10.0.5
Author: Lampwrights.com
Author URI: http://www.lampwrights.com/
*/ 

## If you want to try to use this in the adminCP then uncomment the next line
##define('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE', true);

## Vbulletin mangles these sometimes so let us back them up.
$_GET_BACKUP = $_GET;  $_POST_BACKUP = $_POST;

if ($_GET['action'] == 'activate' and $_GET[plugin] == plugin_basename(__FILE__)) 
{
 $install = true;
}

### Update settings.
if ($_POST['action'] == 'update_vbridge_settings') 
{
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
 {
  update_option('vbb_' . $key, $value); 
 }

 echo "<div class=\"updated\">\n" . "<p>" . "<strong>" . __('Options saved.', 'vbridge') . "</strong>" . "</p>\n" . "</div>\n";
}

if (!$install) 
{ 
 if (!get_option('vbb_VBNOPLUGINS'))
 {
  define('DISABLE_HOOKS', true);
 }

 include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins' . '/vbbridge/vbloader.php'); 

 $vb = VB::instance()->get_vb();
}

$_GET = $_GET_BACKUP; $_POST = $_POST_BACKUP;

add_action('admin_menu', 'Vbridge_Admin');

add_action('the_post', 'bridge_setup_postdata');

add_filter('registration_redirect', 'vbregister');

add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'comment_filter');

add_filter('get_comment_author_link', 'comment_auth_linker');

add_filter('the_author_posts_link', 'get_wp_author');

## Change link to author
function comment_auth_linker($author)
{
 global $vb;

 $vuser = get_vbuser_byname($author);

 return "<a href='" . $vb->options['bburl'] . "/member.php?u=" . $vuser['userid'] . "' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>$author</a>"; 
}

## Change the comment filter
function comment_filter($data)
{
 global $vb;

 $data['logged_in_as'] = '<p class="logged-in-as">Logged in as <a href="' . $vb->options['bburl'] . '/member.php?u=' . $vb->userinfo['userid'] . '">' . $vb->userinfo['username'] . '</a>. <a href="' . $vb->options['bburl'] . '/login.php?do=logout&logouthash=' . $vb->userinfo['logouthash'] . '" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>';

 return $data;
}

## Redirect to VB registration 
function vbregister()
{
 global $vb;

 header('location: '. $vb->options['bburl'] . '/register.php');

 exit;
}

### Present Setup Form.
function Vbridge_Setup() 
{
 global $vb;

 echo "<div class=\"wrap\">\n" . "<h2>" . __('Vbridge Settings', '') . "</h2>\n";

 ?>

 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_vbridge_settings">
 
 Forum Relative Path: <input type=text name=VBRPATH value="<?php echo get_option('vbb_VBRPATH') ?>"> <SMALL>(This is the file directory to your forum.  THIS IS RELATIVE!  If your forum is located at http://www.yourdomain.com/forum then this path would be /forum)</SMALL><P>

 Enable plugins during wordpress instance: No <input type=radio name=VBNOPLUGINS value="0"<?php if (!get_option('vbb_VBNOPLUGINS')) { echo " checked"; } ?>> Yes <input type=radio name=VBNOPLUGINS value="1"<?php if (get_option('vbb_VBNOPLUGINS')) { echo " checked"; } ?>><SMALL>(Most of the time you want this as NO.  Generally plugins are not needed during the wordpress instance and may cause problems.  Enable if instructed or for testing.)</SMALL><P>
 
 <?php
 
 if (is_object($vb)) { echo "Vbulletin has been located and is loaded into memory"; } else { echo "<red>Vbulletin has not been found</red>"; }
 
 ?>
 
 <BR><BR>
 <input type=submit value=Submit>

 <?php

 echo "</form>" . "</div>\n";
}


### Add Vbbridge Settings option to options menu
function Vbridge_Admin() 
{
 add_options_page(
 __('Vbridge&nbsp;Settings', ''),
 __('Vbridge&nbsp;Settings', ''),
 8,
 str_replace("\\", "/", __FILE__),
 Vbridge_Setup
 );
 
 add_submenu_page(
 'profile.php',
 __('Vbridge&nbsp;User&nbsp;Settings', ''),
 __('Vbridge&nbsp;User&nbsp;Settings', ''),
 8,
 str_replace("\\", "/", __FILE__),
 Vbridge_User_Setup
 );
}

### Present User Setup Form.
function Vbridge_User_Setup() 
{
 global $wp_roles, $vb;

 $xx = 0;

 $wpdb =& $GLOBALS['wpdb'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "usergroup";

 $fs = $vb->db->query_read($sql);

 echo "<div class=\"wrap\">\n" . "<h2>" . __('Vbridge User Settings', '') . "</h2>\n";

 ?>

 <style>
 #wpcontent select {
 height: 9em;
 }
 </style>
 
 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_vbridge_settings">
 <table><tr>

 <?php

 while ($group = $vb->db->fetch_array($fs)) 
 {
  if (get_option('vbb_vbugroup_' . $group[usergroupid]) == "") { $selector = ' selected'; } else { $selector = ''; }
 
  $lister = "<option value='0'$selector>Do Not Map</option>\n";

  foreach ($wp_roles->roles as $role) 
  {
   ## Fix for 2.5.1 user role change
 
   $roled = preg_split("/\|/",$role['name']);
 
   $role['name'] = $roled[0];
 
   ## End Fix
 
   if (get_option('vbb_vbugroup_' . $group[usergroupid]) == $role[name]) { $selector = ' selected'; } else { $selector = ''; }
  
   $lister .= "<option value=\"$role[name]\"$selector>$role[name]</option>\n";
  }

  echo "<td>";

  echo "Map VB usergroup: $group[title] to:<BR>";

  echo "\n\n<select class='noclassheh' name='vbugroup_" . $group[usergroupid] . "' size='5'>";
 
  echo $lister;
 
  echo "</select><BR>";
 
  echo "</td>";

  $xx++;

  if ($xx >=2) 
  {
   echo "</tr><tr>";
 
   $xx = 0;
  }
 }

 ?>

 </tr><tr><td colspan=2>
 <center><input type=submit value="Map Users"></center>
 </td>

 <?php

 echo "</form>" . "</tr></table></div>\n";
}

## Get the VB user by user name
function get_vbuser_byname($username)
{
 global $vb;

 if (!is_object($vb)) { return; }

 return $vb->db->query_first("SELECT * from " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user where username = '" . $vb->db->escape_string($username) . "'");
}


## Get WP userinfo, not VB
function get_wp_author($data)
{
 global $authordata, $vb;

 if (is_object($vb) and !defined('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE')) { $vb->options['defer_to_wp'] = true; }

 $link = sprintf(
  '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
  get_author_posts_url( $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ),
  esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Posts by %s' ), get_the_author() ) ),
  get_the_author()
 );

 if (is_object($vb)) { $vb->options['defer_to_wp'] = false; }

 return $link;
}

## This ensures we get the WP data for the author, not VB
function bridge_setup_postdata($post) {
 global $id, $authordata, $day, $currentmonth, $page, $pages, $multipage, $more, $numpages, $vb;

 if (is_object($vb) and !defined('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE')) { $vb->options['defer_to_wp'] = true; }

 $id = (int) $post->ID;

 $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);

 $day = mysql2date('d.m.y', $post->post_date, false);
 $currentmonth = mysql2date('m', $post->post_date, false);
 $numpages = 1;
 $page = get_query_var('page');
 if ( !$page )
  $page = 1;
 if ( is_single() || is_page() || is_feed() )
  $more = 1;
 $content = $post->post_content;
 if ( strpos( $content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) ) {
  if ( $page > 1 )
   $more = 1;
  $multipage = 1;
  $content = str_replace("\n<!--nextpage-->\n", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $content = str_replace("\n<!--nextpage-->", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->\n", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $pages = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $numpages = count($pages);
 } else {
  $pages = array( $post->post_content );
  $multipage = 0;
 }

 if (is_object($vb) and !defined('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE')) { $vb->options['defer_to_wp'] = false; }

 return true;
}

## Sometimes you need the WP user data.  
function get_userdata_orignonbridge( $user_id ) {
 global $wpdb;

 if ( ! is_numeric( $user_id ) )
  return false;

 $user_id = absint( $user_id );
 if ( ! $user_id )
  return false;

 $user = wp_cache_get( $user_id, 'users' );

 if ( $user )
  return $user;

 if ( ! $user = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID = %d LIMIT 1", $user_id ) ) )
  return false;

 _fill_user( $user );

 return $user;
}

###### Function Replacements
if ( (!preg_match('#wp-admin#', $_POST['redirect_to']) and !defined('WP_ADMIN') and !defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') and !$_GET['preview']) or defined('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE')): 
##

## Get bridged users for meta boxes
## Unfortunately WP only passes the output of this to the filter instead of the args so we have to kind of get dirty.
## Basically looking at the class in the output to determine what type of user we are looking for.
## This may bypass some custom stuff out there, but by default I am including editors, authors and administrators when dealing with the author type

add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'bridge_wp_dropdown_users');

function bridge_wp_dropdown_users($data) 
{
 global $post, $user_ID, $vb;

 if (preg_match('#post_author_override#', $data)) 
 { 
  ## This is an author list
 
  $defaults = array(
   'show_option_all' => '', 'show_option_none' => '', 'hide_if_only_one_author' => '',
   'orderby' => 'display_name', 'order' => 'ASC',
   'include' => '', 'exclude' => '', 'multi' => 0,
   'show' => 'authors', 'echo' => 1,
   'selected' => 0, 'name' => 'post_author_override', 'class' => '', 'id' => '',
   'blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'], 'who' => '', 'include_selected' => true
  );
  
  $args = array(
   'who' => 'authors',
   'name' => 'post_author_override',
   'selected' => empty($post->ID) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author,
   'include_selected' => true
  );
 
  $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

  extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

  $show = 'display_name';

  $users = array();

  $ugroups = $vb->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "usergroup");

  while ($group = $vb->db->fetch_array($ugroups)) 
  {
   switch (strtolower(get_option('vbb_vbugroup_' . $group['usergroupid'])))
   {
    case 'administrator':
    case 'author':
    case 'editor':
     $us = $vb->db->query("SELECT userid, username FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user where usergroupid = $group[usergroupid] or FIND_IN_SET($group[usergroupid], membergroupids)");
     while ($u = $vb->db->fetch_array($us)) 
     {
      $obj = new stdClass();

      $obj->ID = $u['userid'];

      $obj->display_name = $u['username'];

      $users[] = $obj;

      unset($obj);
     }
    break;
   }
  }

  $output = '';

  if ( !empty($users) && ( empty($hide_if_only_one_author) || count($users) > 1 ) ) {
   $name = esc_attr( $name );
   if ( $multi && ! $id )
    $id = '';
   else
    $id = $id ? " id='" . esc_attr( $id ) . "'" : " id='$name'";
 
   $output = "<select name='{$name}'{$id} class='$class'>\n";
 
   if ( $show_option_all )
    $output .= "\t<option value='0'>$show_option_all</option>\n";
 
   if ( $show_option_none ) {
    $_selected = selected( -1, $selected, false );
    $output .= "\t<option value='-1'$_selected>$show_option_none</option>\n";
   }
 
   $found_selected = false;
   foreach ( (array) $users as $user ) {
    $user->ID = (int) $user->ID;
    $_selected = selected( $user->ID, $selected, false );
    if ( $_selected )
     $found_selected = true;
    $display = !empty($user->$show) ? $user->$show : '('. $user->user_login . ')';
    $output .= "\t<option value='$user->ID'$_selected>" . esc_html($display) . "</option>\n";
   }
 
   if ( $include_selected && ! $found_selected && ( $selected > 0 ) ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $selected );
    $_selected = selected( $user->ID, $selected, false );
    $display = !empty($user->$show) ? $user->$show : '('. $user->user_login . ')';
    $output .= "\t<option value='$user->ID'$_selected>" . esc_html($display) . "</option>\n";
   }
 
   $output .= "</select>";
  }

  return $output;
 }
 
 else 
 {
  ## Else I haven't built anything for this type, so ignore
  return $data;
 }
}

## Get user avatar URL.  Can be styled with class vbridge_avatar and vbridge_avatar_link
function get_avatar($u, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false )
{
 global $vb;

 if (!is_numeric($u->user_id)) { return; }

 $user = fetch_userinfo($u->user_id);

 if ($avatar = $vb->db->query_first("SELECT dateline, width, height FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "customavatar WHERE userid=" . intval($user['userid'])))
 {
  $safe_alt = esc_attr($user['username']);

  // using a custom avatar
  if ($vb->options['usefileavatar'])
  {
   $user['avatarurl'] = $vb->options['avatarurl'] . '/avatar' . $user['userid'] . '_' . $user['avatarrevision'] . '.gif';
  }
  else
  {
   $user['avatarurl'] = $vb->options['bburl'] . '/image.php?' . $vb->session->vars['sessionurl'] . 'u=' . $user['userid'] . "&amp;dateline=$avatar[dateline]";
  }

  $default = $user['avatarurl'];

  $user['avatarurl'] = "<a class='vbridge_avatar_link' href='" . $vb->options['bburl'] . "/member.php?u={$user['userid']}'><img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$user[avatarurl]}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo avatar-default' width='{$size}' height='{$size}' border='0'/></a>";
 }

 return apply_filters('get_avatar', $user['avatarurl'], $u, $size, $default, $user['username']);
}

## Get the user data of the WP user or the VB user depending on the circumstances
function get_userdata( $user_id ) 
{
 global $wpdb, $vb;

 if (is_object($vb) and !defined('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE')) { if ($vb->options['defer_to_wp']) { return get_userdata_orignonbridge($user_id); } }

 $user_id = absint($user_id);

 if ( $user_id == 0 )
  return false;

 $user = wp_cache_get($user_id, 'users');

 if ( $user )
  return $user;

 if ( !$user_a = $vb->db->query_first("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user WHERE userid = '" . intval($user_id) . "'") )
  return false;

 foreach ($user_a as $key => $value) 
 {
  $user->$key = $value;
 }

 $user->user_login = $user->username;

 $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

 $user->wp_capabilities = $wp_roles->roles[strtolower(get_option('vbb_vbugroup_' . $vb->userinfo[usergroupid]))]['capabilities'];

 $user->ID = $user->userid;

 $user->display_name = $user->username;

 return $user;
}

## Fetch userinfo
function get_userdatabylogin($user_login)
{
 global $wpdb, $vb;

 $user_login = sanitize_user( $user_login );

 if ( empty( $user_login ) )
  return false;

 $user_id = wp_cache_get($user_login, 'userlogins');

 $user = false;
 if ( false !== $user_id )
  $user = wp_cache_get($user_id, 'users');

 if ( false !== $user )
  return $user;

 if ( !$user_a = $vb->db->query_first("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user WHERE username = '" . $vb->db->escape_string($user_login) . "'") )
  return false;

 foreach ($user_a as $key => $value) 
 {
  $user->$key = $value;
 }

 $user->user_login = $user->username;

 return $user;
}

## Authenticate a VB user via WP
function wp_authenticate($username, $password) 
{
 $username = sanitize_user($username);

 if ( '' == $username )
  return new WP_Error('empty_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty.'));

 if ( '' == $password )
  return new WP_Error('empty_password', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password field is empty.'));

 $user = get_userdatabylogin($username);

 if ( !$user || (strtolower($user->user_login) != strtolower($username))) 
 {
  do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $username );
  return new WP_Error('invalid_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username.'));
 }

 $user = apply_filters('wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password);

 if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
  do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $username );
  return $user;
 }

 if ( !wp_check_password($password, $user->user_login) ) 
 {
  do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $username );
  return new WP_Error('incorrect_password', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Incorrect password.'));
 }

 return new WP_User($user->ID);
}

## Validate VB password via WP
function wp_check_password($password, $user_name = '') 
{
 global $vb;

 VB::instance()->require_file('/includes/functions_login.php');
 
 return verify_authentication($user_name,$password,'','',true,true);
}

## Overwrite the cookie check and just go with what VB says
function wp_validate_auth_cookie($cookie = '', $scheme = '') 
{
 global $vb;

 return $vb->userinfo['userid'];
}

## Force the VB user ID
function wp_set_current_user($id, $name = '') 
{
 global $current_user;

 if ( isset($current_user) && ($id == $current_user->ID) )
  return $current_user;

 $current_user = new WP_User($id, $name);

 setup_userdata($current_user->ID);

 do_action('set_current_user');

 return $current_user;
}

endif;

?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: Говнокод в этом плагине, конечно, жесткий, я бы не стал его использовать.

Comment: Вариантов не особо много) Все очень устарело. Есть другой, но там думаю не лучше. И тоже много ошибок -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил проверки, чтобы нотисы убрать:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: vBulletin Wordpress Bridge
Plugin URI: http://www.lampwrights.com/
Description: This plugin will bridge to VB so VB users can comment on articles bridge users.  For detailed instructions please visit <a href='http://www.lampwrights.com'>Lampwrights.com</a>.
Version: 10.0.5
Author: Lampwrights.com
Author URI: http://www.lampwrights.com/
*/ 

## If you want to try to use this in the adminCP then uncomment the next line
##define('USE_ADMINCP_BRIDGE', true);

## Vbulletin mangles these sometimes so let us back them up.
$_GET_BACKUP = $_GET;  $_POST_BACKUP = $_POST;

if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'activate' && isset( $_GET['plugin'] ) && $_GET['plugin'] == plugin_basename(__FILE__)) 
{
    $install = true;
}

### Update settings.
if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update_vbridge_settings') 
{
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
        update_option('vbb_' . $key, $value);   
    }

    echo "<div class=\"updated\">\n" . "<p>" . "<strong>" . __('Options saved.', 'vbridge') . "</strong>" . "</p>\n" . "</div>\n";
}

if ( ! isset( $install ) ) 
{
```

Comment: Это помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну тогда пометьте решением